# Web Service is not getting the xsd file in top down approach

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, xsd, wsdl

I am trying to generate a web service from a wsdl file(Top down Approach) which requires a xsd file. I have successfully created the web service. When i test the webservice from eclipse's browser, it is working fine but when i test it from some other application(in my case i am testing the generated service in WSO2 ESB-Try it section), it doesn't gives me any output. The problem is that when invoking from outside of eclipse, the service is not getting the xsd file. So how could i solve this xsd related problem
My wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/" xmlns:cct="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:standard:CoreComponentType:2">
            <xs:import namespace="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:standard:CoreComponentType:2" schemaLocation="CIRService?xsd=CoreComponentType_2p0.xsd"/>
            <xs:include schemaLocation="CIRService?xsd=CommonInteroperabilityRegistry.xsd"/>


                            <xs:element name="GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRID">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ExistingCIRID" type="cct:IDType"/>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="TargetSourceID" type="cct:IDType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRIDResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Registry" type="tns:Registry"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="DeletePropertiesIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DeleteProperties">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CreateRegistryOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateRegistryResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DeleteEntriesIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DeleteEntries">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetRegistryOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetRegistryResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DeleteCategoryOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DeleteCategoryResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="UpdateRegistryIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateRegistry">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DeleteRegistryIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DeleteRegistry">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DuplicateEntryFault">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DuplicateEntryFault">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DeletePropertiesOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DeletePropertiesResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DeleteRegistryOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DeleteRegistryResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RegistryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="PropertyNotFoundFault">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:PropertyNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="EntryNotFoundFault">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:EntryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="UpdateEntryCIRIDOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateEntryCIRIDResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetRegistryIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetRegistry">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRIDOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRIDResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRIDIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRID">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CreateRegistryFault">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateRegistryFault">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CreateRegistryIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateRegistry">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetEquivalentEntriesIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetEquivalentEntries">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="UpdateEntryCIRIDIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateEntryCIRID">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CreateEquivalentEntryIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateEquivalentEntry">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetEquivalentEntriesOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetEquivalentEntriesResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DeleteCategoryIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DeleteCategory">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DuplicatePropertyFault">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DuplicatePropertyFault">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CategoryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CreateCategoryFault">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateCategoryFault">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DeleteEntriesOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DeleteEntriesResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CreateEquivalentEntryOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateEquivalentEntryResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="UpdateRegistryOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateRegistryResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="CIRService">
    <wsdl:operation name="CreateRegistry">
<wsdl:documentation>Creates a new Registry, new Category in a
                Registry, new Entries in a Category, and Properties with Values in
                an Entry.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:CreateRegistryIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:CreateRegistryOut">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="DuplicatePropertyFault" message="tns:DuplicatePropertyFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="CreateRegistryFault" message="tns:CreateRegistryFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="DuplicateEntryFault" message="tns:DuplicateEntryFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="CreateCategoryFault" message="tns:CreateCategoryFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CreateEquivalentEntry">
<wsdl:documentation>Creates a single Entry and associated Properties,
                and links the new Entry to an existing equivalent Entry. Returns the
                CIRID of the newly created Entry.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:CreateEquivalentEntryIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:CreateEquivalentEntryOut">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" message="tns:CategoryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="DuplicateEntryFault" message="tns:DuplicateEntryFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" message="tns:EntryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" message="tns:RegistryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateRegistry">
<wsdl:documentation>Updates the attributes of existing Registries,
                Categories, Entries or Properties.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:UpdateRegistryIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:UpdateRegistryOut">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" message="tns:CategoryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" message="tns:EntryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" message="tns:RegistryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="PropertyNotFoundFault" message="tns:PropertyNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateEntryCIRID">
<wsdl:documentation>Replaces the CIRID field on matching Entries with
                a new CIRID value.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:UpdateEntryCIRIDIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:UpdateEntryCIRIDOut">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteRegistry">
<wsdl:documentation>Deletes the specified Registry along with its
                Categories, Entries and Properties.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:DeleteRegistryIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:DeleteRegistryOut">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" message="tns:RegistryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteCategory">
<wsdl:documentation>Deletes the specified Category along with its
                Entries and Properties.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:DeleteCategoryIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:DeleteCategoryOut">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" message="tns:CategoryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" message="tns:RegistryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteEntries">
<wsdl:documentation>Deletes the specified Entries along with its
                Properties.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:DeleteEntriesIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:DeleteEntriesOut">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" message="tns:CategoryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" message="tns:EntryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" message="tns:RegistryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteProperties">
<wsdl:documentation>Deletes the specified Properties.
            </wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:DeletePropertiesIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:DeletePropertiesOut">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" message="tns:CategoryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" message="tns:EntryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" message="tns:RegistryNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="PropertyNotFoundFault" message="tns:PropertyNotFoundFault">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetRegistry">
<wsdl:documentation>Returns all Registries, Categories, Entries and
                Properties filtered by the specified conditions.
            </wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetRegistryIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetRegistryOut">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetEquivalentEntries">
<wsdl:documentation>Returns any equivalent Entries to the specified
                existing Entries (i.e. by identifying all Entries with the same
                CIRID to the existing Entries). Multiple entries are specified by
                IDInSource and SourceID pairs. A TargetSourceID or list of
                TargetSourceIDs can be specified to filter returned Entries.
            </wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetEquivalentEntriesIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetEquivalentEntriesOut">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRID">
<wsdl:documentation>Returns any equivalent Entries to the specified
                existing Entry (i.e. by identifying all other Entries with the same
                CIRID to the existing Entry). An Entry is specified by CIRID. A
                Target SourceID or list of SourceIDs can be specified to filter
                returned Entries.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRIDIn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRIDOut">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="CIRServiceSoap12" type="tns:CIRService">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="CreateRegistry">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/CreateRegistry" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="DuplicatePropertyFault">
        <soap12:fault name="DuplicatePropertyFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="CreateRegistryFault">
        <soap12:fault name="CreateRegistryFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="DuplicateEntryFault">
        <soap12:fault name="DuplicateEntryFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="CreateCategoryFault">
        <soap12:fault name="CreateCategoryFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CreateEquivalentEntry">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/CreateEquivalentEntry" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="DuplicateEntryFault">
        <soap12:fault name="DuplicateEntryFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateRegistry">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/UpdateRegistry" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="PropertyNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="PropertyNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateEntryCIRID">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/UpdateEntryCIRID" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteRegistry">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/DeleteRegistry" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteCategory">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/DeleteCategory" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteEntries">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/DeleteEntries" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteProperties">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/DeleteProperties" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="PropertyNotFoundFault">
        <soap12:fault name="PropertyNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetRegistry">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/GetRegistry" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetEquivalentEntries">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/GetEquivalentEntries" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRID">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRID" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="CIRServiceSoap" type="tns:CIRService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="CreateRegistry">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/CreateRegistry" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="DuplicatePropertyFault">
        <soap:fault name="DuplicatePropertyFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="CreateRegistryFault">
        <soap:fault name="CreateRegistryFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="DuplicateEntryFault">
        <soap:fault name="DuplicateEntryFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="CreateCategoryFault">
        <soap:fault name="CreateCategoryFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CreateEquivalentEntry">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/CreateEquivalentEntry" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="DuplicateEntryFault">
        <soap:fault name="DuplicateEntryFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateRegistry">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/UpdateRegistry" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="PropertyNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="PropertyNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateEntryCIRID">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/UpdateEntryCIRID" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteRegistry">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/DeleteRegistry" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteCategory">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/DeleteCategory" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteEntries">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/DeleteEntries" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DeleteProperties">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/DeleteProperties" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="CategoryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="EntryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="RegistryNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
      <wsdl:fault name="PropertyNotFoundFault">
        <soap:fault name="PropertyNotFoundFault" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetRegistry">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/GetRegistry" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetEquivalentEntries">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/GetEquivalentEntries" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRID">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/CIR/GetEquivalentEntriesByCIRID" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="CIRService">
    <wsdl:port name="CIRServiceSoap" binding="tns:CIRServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/CIRService/services/CIRService.CIRServiceSoap/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="CIRServiceSoap12" binding="tns:CIRServiceSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/CIRService/services/CIRService.CIRServiceSoap12/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Plz help

Comment: my main query is how can i successfully refrence the xsd file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just include your original WSDL in you client JAR. Your `wsimport` for your client should have generated a client service class along the following lines:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "TestClient", targetNamespace = "http://namespace", wsdlLocation = "file:/somewhere")
public class TestClient extends Service
{

    private final static URL TESTSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;

    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            URL baseUrl;
            baseUrl = test.clientTestClient.class.getResource(".");
            url = new URL(baseUrl, "file:/somewhere");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.warning("Failed to create URL for the wsdl Location: 'file:/somewhere', retrying as a local file");
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
        TESTSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public TestClient(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public TestClient() {
        super(TESTSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION, new QName("http://namespace", "TestClient"));
    }

    /* ... more stuff ... */

}
```

You could now create an instance of your service like so:

```
new TestClient(getClass().getResource("/wsdlthatisincludedinclientjar.wsdl"), new QName("http://namespace", "TestClient"));
```

Now you just drop your (pre-existing) WSDL (and all depending XSDs) at the root of you client JAR. The only remaining catch is that all depended upon XSDs need to be referenced by a relative URI in you WSDL. 
But since this is you preexisting WSDL you can always edit it to your hearts content.